# Binary Tree Maximum Difference of Labels

Tags: php, binary-tree

I have the below question, but I'm having a hard time making sense of it and implementing it in PHP.

You have a binary tree with **N nodes (1 <= N <= 100000)** numbered from **0** to **N - 1**, each one labeled with some integer. 
You have to answer **Q (1 <= Q <= 75000)** queries, each one denoted by some node (some integer between 0 and N – 1).

The answer for each query is the largest difference between the labels you find in the path from the given node to the root of the tree, which will always be node 0. N will be given in the first line of the input. N lines follow the **i-th** line describes the data of the **i-th** node of the tree (the first line describes node 0, and so on), with 3 integers: label, left child, right child. The absence of any of the children will be denoted by -1. Then a line with the integer Q, followed by Q lines, each one a single query as described above.

**Case 1:**

> For the input provided as follows:
>
> 3
>
> 10 1 2
>
> 12 -1 -1
>
> 15 -1 -1
>
> 2
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> The output of the program will be:
>
> 2
>
> 5

**Case 2:**

> For the input provided as follows:
>
> 3
>
> 10 1 -1
>
> 15 2 -1
>
> 20 -1 -1
>
> 2
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> The output of the program will be:
>
> 5
>
> 10

Getting that maximum difference, for example for case 2,

I'd say output for query two would be 5 because from the data my binary tree has 10(root), then node 15 to the left of the root, then node 20 to the left of 15, so 20-15 is same as 15-10, which makes them both 5. Am I not understanding something here or what ... Any insights are welcome.

Comment: Have you attempted any solution yet yourself?  Stack Overflow tries not be a free code writing service.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , Of course I have ... Am not asking for code actually. Just asking for pointers where I am going wrong in my thinking

Comment: Show what you have tried, it smells like homework.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone See where I say: Getting that maximum difference, for example for case 2, I'd say output for query two would be 5 because from the data my binary tree has 10(root), then node 15 to the left of root, then node 20 to the left of 15, so 20-15 is same as 15-10, which makes them both 5.  That's how I'm thinking about it. The main thing here is understanding the question clearly, once that is done, code is the easy part. All am asking for is someone else take a shot at it we see how they understand it.

Comment: @EricKaburu The answer for each query is the largest difference between the labels you find in the path from the __given node__ to the __root of the tree__, which will always be node 0.

Comment: @mleko, I know that. How am I arriving at 5 for case 2 query 2 and how they arriving at 10 is what am trying to figure out. On that tree there are 3 nodes, root(Label 10), node with label 15 and node with label 20. Looking at the data descriptions, node with label 15 is parent to node with label 20, so on the path from 20 to root, there is 15 meaning label difference there is 5. Then from 15 we just go to root and 15-10 = 5. Those two are the same meaning highest difference is 5. If the 3rd node was labelled let's say 27, the highest difference is 27-15 which is 12.

Comment: @EricKaburu in case 2 you have chain 10-15-20, max(10,15,20) - min(10,15,20) gives 10. I case of chain 33-11-27-87-3 you get max(33,11,27,87,3) - min(33,11,27,87,3) => 87-3 => 84

Answer (score 0):

Take into considerations **all** nodes between **root** and **given node**

> For the input provided as follows:
>
> 3
>
> 10 1 -1
>
> 15 2 -1
>
> 20 -1 -1
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> The output of the program will be:
>
> 10

you get path `10-15-20` you should go with

```
max(10,15,20) - min(10,15,20) => 10
```

> For the input provided as follows:
>
> 7
>
> 33 1 5
>
> 11 2 -1
>
> 27 3 6
>
> 87 4 -1
>
> 3 -1 -1
>
> 666 -1 -1
>
> 6666 -1 -1
>
> 1
>
> 4
>
> The output of the program will be:
>
> 84

you get longer chain `33-11-27-87-3` you get

```
max(33,11,27,87,3) - min(33,11,27,87,3) => 87-3 => 84
```

Comment: This will simply mean the difference is always the label of Q(current query) - (minus) the root node label which always will have the least label value. You're not considering inter node differences and the structure of the tree based on the data. Some node may be a sibling not a parent on our way back to root, so it does not get used in finding the diffrences

Comment: @EricKaburu why you assume nodes are ordered? Check case `33-11-27-87-3` where root is smaller than biggest node and leaf have smallest value. each one(node) labeled with __some__ integer.

Comment: @EricKaburu by chain I mean all nodes from __root__ to __given node__, siblings are not important

Comment: I think we are understanding this question differently. My thinking, the first thing is one should be able to tell apart the siblings and parent of some node (from the data descriptions given). This is because a sibling **CAN NOT** be on my path as I trace my way up to the root. But anyways I appreciate your help, thanks for your insights

Comment: @EricKaburu We understand it same way, I updated my answer to be more verbose

Comment: How would it look like as tree structure?

Comment: Thanks mleko, As per description "i-th line describes the data of the i-th node of the tree" with 3 integers: label, left child, right child, with your example, for 0th line there are 33 1 5 that means 33 is label 1 left and 5 right child. (As per my understanding). which is contradict with your given tree.

Let me correct if I am wrong.

Comment: @GhostRider given example from question `10 1 2` I understand as 10-label, 1-id(line, not label) of left child, 2-id(line, not label) of right child. `33 1 5` would mean 33-label, 1-line of left child (one with label 11), 5-line of right child (one with  label 666). I see no contradiction here